# Is there a tag for industry?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Operations Research SE has tag [academia](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia) and tag [government](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government). However, I find no tag for industry. Since there are several questions on operations research in industry, I propose that tag [industry](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry) be created.

Comment: I suggested that the tag be created and it was approved. Suggested that a few questions be-retagged, too. Not yet approved.

Comment: Also created [tag:logistics] and [tag:military].

Comment: More important than tag creation is tag **usage guidance** and the accompanying tag wiki.